# Sybase Synchronization Group in iPhone

Tags: iphone, synchronization, sup

I am using Sybase Unwired Platform in my iPhone application.I created MBO 's using SAP functional modules.I am following the iOS developer guide 2.1 ESD #3 to creating my application.I have some Synchronization groups in my SUP server.I need to synchronize a particular group from my iPhone client application.I tried with "beginSynchronize" and "submitPendingOperations" method but it is not synchronizing.When I tried with "synchronizeWithListener" method it works but not a specific group.I need to increase the synchronization speed by synchronizing a specific group or a specific MBO.

I am new to SUP. Any help is appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you DB generated class, you have the following methods:

```
/*!
  @method 
  @abstract synchronize the synchronizationGroup with server.
  @discussion
  @throws SUPPersistenceException
*/
 + (void)synchronize;

/*!
   @method 
   @abstract synchronize the synchronizationGroups with server, using custom syncStatusListener.
   @discussion
   @throws SUPPersistenceException
 */
  + (void)synchronizeWithListener:(id<SUPSyncStatusListener>) listener;

/*!
   @method 
   @abstract synchronize the synchronizationGroup with server, using custom syncStatusListener.
   @discussion
   @throws SUPPersistenceException
*/
  + (void)synchronize:(NSString *)synchronizationGroup withListener:(id<SUPSyncStatusListener>)listener;

/*!
   @method 
   @abstract synchronize the synchronizationGroup with server.
   @discussion
   @throws SUPPersistenceException
 */
 + (void)synchronize:(NSString*)synchronizationGroup;
```

The ones taking the parameter **synchronizationGroup** are the ones you need to use in your case (with of without listener depending if you want sync or async operations).

Also, remember that if your MBOs have synchronization parameters, they won't be synchronized in the main synchronize/synchronizeWithListener methods.

Comment: Thank you very much PsychoWood."+ (void)synchronize:(NSString *)synchronizationGroup withListener:(id<SUPSyncStatusListener>)listener;" method works fine.I tried this method before but I am specified the synchronization group name in capital letters.Now I tried with the small letters, then it worked.But the speed of synchronization is still a problem.I thought that using Syn. Group will increase the  synchronization speed.But it remains same.

Comment: You're welcome. You can speed up the synchronization a bit more using the method without a listener, don't expect miracles, tho. :)